# Fix table vertical & horizontal line spacing

Tags: tables

Having the following code as an example of a table :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
     
        \caption{Dummy Table}
        \centering
      
        \begin{tabular} {c||c|c|c||c|c|c} \toprule[2.0pt]
            \textbf{Category of }    & \multicolumn{3}{c||} 
           {\textbf{Average Prices}} & \multicolumn{3}{c} 
           {\textbf{Production Time}} \\ \cline{2-4} \cline{5-7}
            \textbf{Products    } & A   & B   & C   & A & B & C \\ \toprule[2.0pt]
            Fruits                & 1\% & 2\% & 3\% & A & D & G \\ 
            Meat                  & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & B & E & H \\ 
            Vegetables            & 7\% & 8\% & 9\% & C & F & I \\ \toprule[2.0pt]
        \end{tabular}

    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

We obtain the following result:
[image: example]

For this example, I have two questions that I didn't manage to solve on myself

#### A

Regarding the two vertical lines that intersect with the horizontal line. Can this be avoided somehow? I tried in the example above to use the `\cline` from cell number 2 to cell number 4 and then from cell number 5 to cell number 7 but that clearly did not solve the issue as you can see. Is it possible for the vertical lines to stop before and after the two horizontal lines that dissect the table (||) ?

#### B

Regarding the spacing below the `\toprule[2.0pt]` that I have placed there. Can this space be shrinked and touch the rule that I have placed above it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines from `booktabs`, by design, are not made to be used with verticla lines, because they have some vertical padding. I propose to replace these lines  with the variable thickness lines  from the `makecell` package, and the `\cline`s with a single `hhlines`, which gives you control on the way horizontal and vertical lines intersect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, hhline}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{Dummy Table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular} {c||c|c|c||c|c|c} \Xhline{2.0pt}
            \multirowthead{2.75}{Category of\\ Products} & \multicolumn{3}{c||}
           {\thead{Average\\ Prices}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}
           {\thead{Production\\ Time}} \\ \hhline{~||---||---}
            & A & B & C & A & B & C \\ \Xhline{2.0pt}
            Fruits & 1\% & 2\% & 3\% & A & D & G \\
            Meat & 4\% & 5\% & 6\% & B & E & H \\
            Vegetables & 7\% & 8\% & 9\% & C & F & I \\ \Xhline{2.0pt}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have done well to provide what the OP was after. Pity it looks so cluttered and offputing to a reader.

Comment: @PeterWilson: Personally, I'm not necessarily against horizontal rules, but I would  have used some pale grey thick rules to make it more pleasing to the eye.

Comment: To my eye it is the verticals not the horizontals.

Comment: Sorry for my *lapsus calami*. I meant of  course vertical rules

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting? Is it the color or the thickness of the vertical lines that create the issue of "offputting-ness" and/or "cluttering-ness"?

Comment: @ex1led: I thought  it would look better with coloured  thick horizontal rules (some light grey, for instance), and possibly  make these rules the same thickness as the overall width of the double rules (namely, 2.8pt).

Comment: @ex1led It is the existance of the vertical lines that make the clutter.

Comment: Noted! thank you for the suggestions. I will take them into account and change the table as instructed. I definitely don't want to obfuscate things. Much obliged.